# How can I add instagram, facebook story options to share bottomsheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: I want to get the same one]

I need facebook ,instagram and twitter sharing from bottomsheet.Is there any way of doing it?

Maybe it shoud do with native code,but I think there should be a way of doing it.
i tried some packages of pub dev but it did not help me

Answer (score 2):

I think https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus will it your need.

It is a plugin to share content from your Flutter app via the platform's share dialog. Do go through its documentation.

Comment: Thanks sir,I have tried this package,but it does not provide these features